# sum of a non singular symmetric matrix and the matrix of its eigenvalues is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, multilinear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I am looking for a proof for this lemma: Assume $\Phi$ is a real, symmetric and non-singular matrix of order $T\times T$ with non-negative elements; Let define $B=(u_1,...,u_T)$ as a column matrix of the eigenvectors of $\Phi$ and $\Gamma_T=diag(\gamma_1,...,\gamma_T)$ is a diagonal matrix that consists of the corresponding eigenvalues of $\Phi$. Then $\Phi+\Gamma_T$ is an invertible matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by *the* eigenvectors? Do you mean that each column of $B$ is some eigenvector of $\Phi$ chosen such the set of all columns is linearly independent?

Comment: yes. that's correct

Comment: Then Marc van Leeuwen answered your question hours ago.

Comment: The matrix $B$ is constructed and then forgotten, curious.

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong, with or without the hypothesis of non-negative entries (which was added to the question after I originally posted this answer). Take $\Phi=\pmatrix{\sqrt2/2&1\\1&\sqrt2/2}$ and $B=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}$, then $\Gamma_T=\pmatrix{\sqrt2/2+1&0\\0&\sqrt2/2-1}$ and $\Phi+\Gamma_T=\pmatrix{\sqrt2+1&1\\1&\sqrt2-1}$ is non invertible.

Comment: how about when every element on the matrix $\Phi$ is non negative?

Comment: @karosolat A sum of two (symmetric) positive definite matrices is positive definite, so non singular. So in that case indeed $\Phi+\Gamma_T$ is invertible.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : OP said $\Phi$ has all positive entries, but that doesn't mean that it is positive definite. It may have one or more negative eigen values. So its not really sum of two pd matrices.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: right, I missed that when I wrote my comment. I've modified the answer to satisfy the condition of positivity.